# Android Studio compile error:com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Ljava_cup/runtime/ComplexSymbolFactory

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, build.gradle

I get this error when trying to compile an android studio project, that uses the "weka" machine learning algorithm. The project is part of an uni assignment, just to be clear.

the build.gradle looks like this:

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ac.univie.em2.project"
        minSdkVersion 24
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    buildToolsVersion '26.0.2'
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka/weka-stable
    implementation 'nz.ac.waikato.cms.weka:weka-stable:3.8.0'
}
```

Things we already tried:
1) adding the multidexenabled true flag
2) clean and rebuild

EDIT: We found a workaround, by not using maven for the weka dependency, but using the 3.6.6 jar directly. I would still love it if someone could tell me what the problem in out build.gradle file is

Comment: Add `dexOptions {
    preDexLibraries = false
} in build.gradle`.

Comment: @ADM That didn't work unfortunately, we still get the same exception